# upload image to Facebook with Intent Android

Tags: android, facebook, android-intent

I want to upload image to facebook or/and other services, and with , for example, what's up works fine, my picture is send to any contact i choose, but when i pick Facebook on dialog chooser it opens my Facebook App, but says "One or more media items could not be added"

Here is my code how i do it:

```
    String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath()+"/image.jpg";
    Uri imageUri = Uri.parse(file_path);
    Intent share = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    share.setType("image/jpg");

    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, imageUri);
    share.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "My Image");

    startActivity(Intent.createChooser(share, "Share Image"));
```